# How to create the following lists with list comprehensions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

How to create the following lists using a list comprehension in python:

```
list1 = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,.........n,n,n,n,n]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5...................]
```

In `list1`, each number is repeated 5 times.
`list2` has 5*n elements, where `n` is user defined.

Just curious if this is possible using a list comprehension.

```
list1=[]
x=0
for i in range(5*n):
    if i%5==0 and i>0 :       
       x+=1
    list1.append(x)
```

Comment: What have you tried, and how was it deficient?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first question:
`[i for i in range(n) for j in range(5)]`

your second question:
`[j for i in range(k) for j in range(1,6)]`

where `k` is the number of repeats

Comment: first `[i for i in range(n) for j in range(5)]`

Comment: @splash58 true, i accidenlty read it as from 1 to n, sorry about that :), thank you

Comment: seems, the second should be `[j for i in range(n) for j in range(1,6)]`

Comment: @splash58 as hes test case show i can not know that :)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski true, my wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

Avoiding the (explicit) nested loops:

1. `sum([[x]*5 for x in range(1,n+1)],[])`
   (Per @StevenRumbalski's suggestion, a better approach would be `itertools.chain(*[[x]*5 for x in range(1,n+1)])`, which yields an iterable of the values you want.)
2. `[x for x in range(1,6)]*n`

Comment: `sum([[x]*5 for x in range(1,6)],[])` is really `sum([[x]*5 for x in range(1,n+1)],[])` and performs horribly as `n` grows as each addition on the list creates a new list and copies all old elements.

Comment: @chepner: Given no info about how it will be used (if at all), hard to assess the likelihood of a problem.

Comment: Let me be more straightforward.  Adding lists with `sum` in Python is a code smell to me due to its performance characteristics.  The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) seems to hint at the same saying that sum is normally used for numbers and then provides examples of how not to use `sum` for other common types, including iterables. One could argue this is premature optimization, but why write code that can bite you when other equally clear alternatives exist?